# How to Update Graylog version in docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, graylog2, graylog

I am new to graylog, I have installed graylog in docker and after installing it I observed 2 notifications one is related to Graylog Upgrade. Can someone tell me how to update it using docker commands?

Note: First in need to take backup of my data and then I need to update it to version 2.4.6.

Note 2: I have already referred the documentation in graylog.

http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/upgrade.html

http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/installation/docker.html

**Graylog Installation process:**

docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3 
docker run --name elasticsearch \ 
    -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \ 
    -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.2 
docker run --link mongo --link elasticsearch \ 
    -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \ 
    -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api" \ 
    -d graylog/graylog:2.4.0-1

[image]

Comment: Did you try docs of graylog? Does it mention how to upgrade?

Comment: I have done all the research. I haven't found anywhere. @Light.G

Comment: Does this help somehow? http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/upgrade.html ?

Comment: @Light.G in that they have not mentioned related to Docker Update. I have already referred the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i have installed graylog with my own volumes

```
docker run --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
           -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
           -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api" \
           -d graylog/graylog:2.4.0-1
```

Now stop graylog using

```
docker stop [graylog Container ID]
```

Now remove container from docker

```
docker rm [graylog Container ID]
```

Now Remove docker image

```
docker rmi [graylog Image ID]
```

Now again install graylog by changing the graylog version

```
docker run --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
           -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
           -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api" \
           -d graylog/graylog:2.4.6-1
```

**Note: Only remove graylog not mongoDB/Elasticsearch. Then you won't loose any data.**

Answer (score 1):

To use the latest version change the tag of the graylog image from `2.4.0-1` to `2.4` or `2.4.6-1`

Seems like the documentation you found is not completely in line with the [documentation on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/):

> If you simply want to checkout Graylog without any further customization, you can run the following three commands to create the necessary environment:
>
> `docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3`
>
> `docker run --name elasticsearch \
>       -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
>       -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.12`
>
> `docker run --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
>       -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
>       -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api" \
>       -d graylog/graylog:2.4`